# I only retrieve one line of data PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I was fetching the data in a while loop, and everything was fine, but now I entered another mysql fetch inside that while loop to go get some specific data for that loop id, but it only returns me the first row , its like the mysql fetch data query I do in the middle is blocking the previous query :S

Here is the code:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                    $checkifexists = "SELECT * FROM `excuroffic` WHERE excursionid=:exc AND officeid=:off";
                    $check_params = array(
                        ':exc' => $row['id'],
                        ':off' => $_GET['office']
                    );

                    try
                    {
                        $stmt = $db->prepare($checkifexists);
                        $result = $stmt->execute($check_params);
                        $reply = $stmt->rowCount();
                        if($reply!=0)
                            $getprices = $stmt->fetch();
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $ex)
                    {
                        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
                    }
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td>&euro;<?php if($reply == 0) echo "0.00"; else echo $getprices['adult']; ?></td>
                <td>&euro;<?php if($reply == 0) echo "0.00"; else echo $getprices['child']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="index.php?p=payment_edit&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&office=<?php echo $_GET['office']; ?>">Edit Prices</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

PLEASE assume that the while loop is working fine because if I remove the second query inside the while loop it shows all the records.

So why does the query inside the loop makes the loop break on the first data return :S

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the value of $stmt (and hence, of $row) the very first time the while() condition is evaluated?!

Comment: or are you "reusing" the variable name $stmt from some query above this code and also in the try{} block in this code?

Comment: SOLVED thank you very much @RobP your point showed me that I was changing the value of the while loop because I was changing the $stmt value inside the second query.. Dump me but you know you can't see some obvious stuff after lot of hours of coding. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inside loop, dont use `$stmt`, you are overrinding the first loop variable. Just change the variable name in the inside loop for something like `$stmt_2` or something more relevant

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
             ^^^^--- $stmt from previous query
    ....
        try
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($checkifexists);
            ^^^^^---overwrites previous $stmt
```